# jquery dojo tree structure

Tags: jquery, dojo

Can someone recommend me a framework/library that has a a tree like  structure and which will display tables/datas or content on the right side.

any working examples/demo would be much appreciated..
Also, I want  to add. is there any tools or libraries that allow the user to edit the left navigation  in the right column or left column and update it..

I would say user editable navigation examples

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is [dijit.Tree](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Tree.html) in Dojo and there are some [plugins for jQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/tree) (the [jQuery UI Tree](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tree) is not ready yet).